# ObservableHQ faceted plot remove x-axes ticks

Tags: javascript, observablehq

I am trying to get rid of x-axis ticks for individual bar plots in this faceted plot. This plot is generated using ObservableHQ's Plot object.

```
Plot.plot({
  marginLeft: 10,
  marginRight: 10,
  label: null,
  y: { padding: 0, label: "Channels (Log_2)" },
  color: {
    legend: true,
  },
  marks: [
    Plot.barY(processed_data, {
      fx: "layer",
      x: "concept",
      y: "channel",
      fill: "concept",
      inset: 0.5,
    }),
    Plot.ruleX([0])
  ],
});
```

I want the ticks to be removed from the bottom, because it is redundant as the class is encoded as colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be disabled by simply specifying an empty tick list.

```
Plot.plot({
  marginLeft: 10,
  marginRight: 10,
  label: null,
  y: { padding: 0, label: "Channels (Log_2)" },
  color: {
    legend: true,
  },
  marks: [
    Plot.barY(processed_data, {
      fx: "layer",
      x: "concept",
      y: "channel",
      fill: "concept",
      inset: 0.5,
    }),
    Plot.axisX({ticks: []}),
    Plot.ruleX([0])
  ],
});
```